# EIther looping in login or screen becomes yellow and red while using xorg

Tags: nvidia, login, xorg, 22.04

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to work things out. So I would like to try out login option with xorg to be able to share screen. But it either sends me back to login page after a black screen, or shows me yellow and red theme screen. For the second option, if I try to enter the settings in instantly logs me out.

I tried to update my Nvidia drivers inside Ubuntu, checked something called Xauthorization (which doesnt even seem to exist in my system). Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to update my Nvidia drivers to version 525 through Ubuntu's "Software Updates" section.